# Having an else for if name == __main__ in python

Tags: python, module

I have two different sets of behavior I want to default private (`_` prefixed) values for a package to have if it is run as main vs. if it is imported. I was thinking of just adding an `else` to my `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement. Is there a more pythonic way to do this? Is this a code smell?

Comment: So, you want to execute a certain set of behaviour if the module is being imported?

Comment: Yes. I know that's what this would do. I am just not sure if there is a better way or if this is bad practice

Comment: I've got to say, it's a bit difficult imagining a proper use case for this. Although I suppose you could just put the code in global scope, and make sure you have a `sys.exit` call or something in your `if` block.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Basically I have a default value that is used if the module is imported but it can be defined by command line arg if you run the module. The module is instantiated dynamically in what would typically would be the `main` call but because it is dynamically instantiated the `__name__` isn't `__main__`. Either way I want the behavior to be slightly different

Comment: Just set the default value when you declare the video at the top. In your `if __name__ == '__main__'`, just change the variable using the command line arguments. Then afterwards, just run the `main` call to "setup" the module.

Comment: @Zizouz212 That's preferable to an else on the main?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151627/discussion-between-ford-prefect-and-zizouz212).